# Async fn with &self receiver that returns impl Future + 'static

Tags: rust

I have a long-running `async fn` that borrows `&self`. I can't separate it from `&self` without cloning the whole structure (which I will likely do), but I'm curious if it's possible to drop the reference to make the future effectively `'static`.

I know I can create an async block after the setup code, then convert it into a `Box<dyn Future<...> + 'static>`, but that's a lot of boilerplate that's not really needed.

Details:

I have a structure behind an `RwLock` and I will need to periodically run a long-lived async task on it, but I don't want to block mutations during that time. I know there's a lot of boiler-plate ways to work around the lifetime issues, but I'd like to know if there's some way to drop the reference to `&self` without that.

This is similar to what I have:

```rust
impl Foo {
    pub async fn long(&self) -> _ {
        // some setup logic that uses &self but doesn't keep a reference

        let _ = self; // explicitly drop &self

        tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;

        // more logic that only uses local fields

        // eventually return a status, which may be used by some consumer
    }
}
```

Comment: As Rust futures are lazy/cold, the code before `let _ = self` will also run as part of the future. It will therefore always need to contain the reference to self.

Comment: Also, `let _ = self` doesn't drop anything, since `self` is just a shared reference and is as such `Copy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, in a way, but not with the `async fn` syntax sugar, instead you can return an `impl Future` and precisely control what is captured in your function:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
struct Foo;
impl Foo {
    pub fn long(&self) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'static {
        // your setup logic that extracts the 'static info necessary for your future
        async move {
            // do not mention `self` in here
            tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        }
    }
}
```

The `'static` bound on the returned `Future` is actually already implied, and included here only for clarity.